# Menu disappears with custom post type link

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, filters, genesis-theme-framework

I’m working with Genesis Theme for a while but never got any problems:)

This is my first big issue and I dont know how to solve it. I’m making a new website with Custom Post Types and WP All Import plugin. Everything is working fine but I made some kind of filter to filter by a custom post type. Filter is working as it should be but after page reload my Main menu is gone.

This is the page I mean. (not live yet so you may see some bugs)

Without filter and with menu: [With Menu](http://www.simonly.direct/sim-only-abonnementen/simyo/)

With filter and without menu: [Without Menu](http://www.simonly.direct/sim-only-abonnementen/simyo/?contract=12%20maanden)

Someone has an idea why this is happening and how I can solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

Joep

**This is the filter in my functions.php**

```
    // action
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    // bail early if is in admin
    if( is_admin() ) {

        return;

    }


    // get meta query
    $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

    if(!empty($_GET['contract']))
    {
        $contract = explode(',', $_GET['contract']);
        $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'contract',
        'value' => $_GET['contract'],
        'compare' => 'IN',
        );
    }

    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

    return;
}
```

Comment: what does your filter look like? remember that query filters run for every query on a page, including ones that load menu items. you have to target them correctly.

Comment: Hello, thx for the fast reply, the script is in my post now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pre_get_posts` filters will be applied to all queries on a page- the main query, menus, and additional WP_Query instances.

To target only the main query, use [`is_main_query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query):

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    // bail early if is in admin
    // or if query is not main query
    if( is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }

    // get meta query
    $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

    if(!empty($_GET['contract']))
    {
        $contract = explode(',', $_GET['contract']);
        $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'contract',
        'value' => $_GET['contract'],
        'compare' => 'IN',
        );
    }

    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

    return;
}
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks for your good explanation and help!:)